# How to update stripe payment data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am trying to update data attribute from input value. i am trying this way but not work `data-description=$("#stripeAmount").val();`

```
    <form action="paymentStrip" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="stripeAmount" id="stripeAmount" value="35" />        
    <input type="hidden" name="itemid" id="itemid" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business_category" id="business_category" value="1" />
    <script
           src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
           data-key="pk_test_pa9c33hPMCuAV941sMktI5Mw"
           data-image="http://www.phpgang.com/wp-content/themes/PHPGang_v2/img/logo.png"
          data-name="PHPGang.com"
           data-description=$("#stripeAmount").val();>
   </script>

   </form>
```

Comment: you cannot use a js-function that way in an html attribute. You could make a function (that gets called when user edits 'stripeAmount') which updates that attribute.

Comment: is there any alternative way @Jeff

Comment: other question: can't you just hardcode the value 35 into data-description? where does this value come from?

Comment: come from <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$r->id.'">. modal call set value in hidden input  @Jeff

Comment: then you can also set the data-description when setting the value in hidden input! `$('.stripe-button').dataset.description = value;` (might not work in IE)

Answer (score 0):

To change the value on change use:

```
$('#stripeAmount').change(function () {
   $('#stripeScript').attr('data-description', $(this).val())
});
```

You also have to add `id="stripeScript"` to the stripe `<script>` tag.

***NOTE***: that being said, I am not sure if this actually does anything. You may have to remove the stripe script and create it for it to have effect. I am not familiar with the stripe API